# PutItemRequest results in errors

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I use Nuget to download some packages about AWS dynamoDb and AWS Core.
But I was trying to do something to my dynamoDB, the header file results in awful errors:

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<aws\core\Aws.h>
#include<aws\dynamodb\DynamoDBClient.h>
#include<aws\dynamodb\DynamoDBRequest.h>
#include<aws\dynamodb\model\AttributeValue.h>
#include<aws\dynamodb\DynamoDB_EXPORTS.h>
#include<aws\dynamodb\DynamoDBEndpoint.h>
#include<aws\dynamodb\DynamoDBErrorMarshaller.h>
#include<aws\dynamodb\DynamoDBErrors.h>
#include<aws\core\auth\AWSCredentialsProvider.h>
#include<aws\core\platform\Environment.h>
#include<aws\core\platform\FileSystem.h>
using namespace std;
class CMyFrame : public CFrameWnd {
public:
CMyFrame() {
    Create(NULL, _T("MFC Application Tutorial"));
}
};

class CExample : public CWinApp {
BOOL InitInstance() {
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);

    CMyFrame *Frame = new CMyFrame();
    m_pMainWnd = Frame;

    Frame->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
    Frame->UpdateWindow();
    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);

    return TRUE;
}
};

CExample theApp;
```

The above code works normally, but when I add `#include<aws\dynamodb\model\PutItemRequest.h>` without changing any other code, build it and it will display:

```
 expected an identifier, syntax error:','    ',':unexpected token,expected either '}' or a ','.
```

why this happens ? I just include one more header file. The header file is provided by amazon sdk, it cannot have synatx error.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef WIN32  // PutItemRequest.h collides with Microsoft macros
   #ifdef IN
      #undef IN
   #endif
#endif
#include <aws/dynamodb/model/PutItemRequest.h>
```

Comment: This is way underrated answer. Thanks!